# Code works in Activity but don't work in other Activity

Tags: android-studio, imageview

I tried to show my App logo in the main activity but the image view does not show

I used this code to show the app logo in the main activity but the image view does not show, however the same code works fine in the splash activity.
1.

1. java
2. logo = findViewById(R.id.Logo);
3. if (isDarkThemeEnabled){
4. logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.dark_logo);
5. }else {
6. logo.setImageResource(R.drawable.light_logo);
7. }
8. xml
9. <ImageView
10. android:id="@+id/Logo"
11. android:layout_above="@+id/buttonsLayout"
12. android:layout_width="@dimen/height_width_small"
13. android:layout_height="@dimen/height_width_small"
14. 